# Keep build object when preload association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to build some virtual object without saving them in database yet, but I have trouble when using `includes` method to preload data and prevent N + 1 query.
For example: A `form` object has many `fields`, and it also has many `conditions`.

```rb
class Form
  has_many :fields
  has_many :conditions

  def custom_fields
    (first_field second_field).each do |name|
      fields.build(name: name)
    end
    fields # this is included two new build object above with without id
  end
end
```

When using `includes`

```rb
form.custom_fields.includes(:fields, :conditions)
```

The two new object is gone away. Is there any ways I can do preload but keep the build object?

Comment: You can't use `includes` if the objects aren't saved. If this is in `#new` procedure, then you'll need to save in order for it to work. If you're worried about saving the object, you might be best off creating a `table_copy` of your table, inserting into that, then you can perform your checks and finally copy/save it to the main table

Comment: Could you explain the problem in a wider context, please? Let's imagine you did manage to have a mix of a persisted and newly built items - what's next?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov
In my application, there are some condition if a form has, and it is displayed as a field, but now new logic come, I want to build new field to display as a hidden field in the form data, and it also get data to that field when the form is submitted

Comment: Given your complex comment above, it would help if you edited your question to include the actual .erb file for the form, and the controller code. Also examples of expected behavior and data structure.

Comment: dont mix scopes and initialization -period-